# How do I track the 'this' pointer when it is used with the clang analyzer?

Tags: clang, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

In my attempts to learn how to use the clang static analyzer, I've discovered that the `checkLocation` callback doesn't fire when the `this` pointer is accessed. Although this kind of makes sense, since it's sort of a "special" pointer, I'd like to be able to track `this` as it is referenced and passed between various functions.

For example, given the following function:

```
// test_program.cpp

class ThisTest
{
public:
    ThisTest() {};
    void callTestFunction(int x);
};

void TestFunction(ThisTest *test, int anotherArgument)
{
    // do nothing
}

void ThisTest::callTestFunction(int x)
{
    // call TestFunction(a, x)
    ThisTest *a = new ThisTest();
    TestFunction(a, x);

    // call TestFunction(this, x) where a == this
    delete a;
    a = this;
    TestFunction(a, x);

    // call TestFunction(this, x) directly
    TestFunction(this, x);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ThisTest myTest;
    myTest.callTestFunction(argc);
    return 0;
}
```

and the following checker:

```
// this_analyzer.cpp

#include <clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/Checker.h>
#include <clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/PathSensitive/CheckerContext.h>
#include <clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/PathSensitive/CallEvent.h>
#include <clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/CheckerRegistry.h>

using namespace clang;
using namespace ento;

class ThisAnalyzer : public Checker < check::PreCall,
                                      check::Location
                                    >
{
public:
    ThisAnalyzer() {};
    void checkLocation(SVal loc, bool isLoad, const Stmt *S, CheckerContext &C) const;
    void checkPreCall(const CallEvent &call, CheckerContext &C) const;
};

void ThisAnalyzer::checkLocation(SVal loc, bool isLoad, const Stmt *S, CheckerContext &C) const
{
    llvm::errs() << "Location: " << loc << '\n';
}

void ThisAnalyzer::checkPreCall(const CallEvent &call, CheckerContext &C) const
{
    llvm::errs() << "PreCall: ";
    call.dump();
}

extern "C"
void clang_registerCheckers( CheckerRegistry &registry )
{
    registry.addChecker<ThisAnalyzer>("thisAnalyzer", "how do i computer");
}

extern "C"
const char clang_analyzerAPIVersionString[] = CLANG_ANALYZER_API_VERSION_STRING;
```

I run the following command, and receive this output:

```
$ clang++ -Xclang -load -Xclang ./libthis_analyzer.so -Xclang -analyzer-checker=core,thisAnalyzer -Xclang -analyze -Xclang -analyzer-output=text -Xclang -analyze-function=callTestFunction -c test_program.cpp
PreCall: 
Location: &a
Location: &x
PreCall: TestFunction(a, x)
Location: &a
Location: &a
Location: &a
Location: &x
PreCall: TestFunction(a, x)
Location: &x
PreCall: TestFunction(this, x)
```

As you can see, the third `checkPreCall` callback is only preceded by a single `checkLocation` callback for `&x` as opposed to the two callbacks for `&a` and `&x` in the previous two calls to `TestFunction`.

I have found that I can add something like this to `checkPreCall`:

```
unsigned argCount = call.getNumArgs();

for (unsigned i=0; i < argCount; i++)
{
    SVal arg = call.getArgSVal(i);
    llvm::errs() << "Arg " << i << ": " << arg << '\n';
}
```

And I get output like:

```
Arg 0: &SymRegion{reg_$0<this>}
Arg 1: reg_$6<x>
```

But I'm not sure how to recognize programmatically that this is a symbolic region for a `this` pointer, short of doing some string parsing that I'd rather not do, because it seems like a hack. I thought that maybe I could `dyn_cast<CXXThisRegion>()` the region, but it turns out that the `SymbolicRegion` and `CXXThisRegion` don't share the same inheritance chain.

**What is the best way to track the `this` pointer and recognize when it is being referenced or passed to another function? Am I completely off the mark as to how to do something like this?**